# Simplify R1C1 code

Tags: excel, vba

How can i simplify the following code? I'd like to add variables where possible and allow for a loop.

```
'3
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 5) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1)
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 5) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2)
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 5) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 3)

Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 6) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1)
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 6) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2)
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 6) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 3)

Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 7) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1)
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 7) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 2)
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 7) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 3)

'2
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 8) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1)
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 8) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2)
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 8) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 3)

Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 9) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1)
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 9) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 2)
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 9) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 3)

'1
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 10) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 1)
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 10) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 2)
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 10) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 3)
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's the logic in the right part of each row? It's not that obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a start, you can use:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .cells(x,y) = .cells(a,b)
    ...
End With
```

Using "For ... Next" loops for your row and column indices should be pretty straightforward.